# warning C4673: throwing 'ex::traced_error<EX>' the following types will not be considered at the catch site

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

MSVC 10 and MSVC 9 are both  generating a level 4 warning message when compiling my exception framework, although the behavior of the program seems correct.  The exception framework is rather large & complex, but I have managed to boil it down to its essence.  This is a complete program you can compile & run in VS10

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

    namespace ex
    {
        class generic_error : virtual public std::exception
        {
        public:
            generic_error(int thread_id) : thread_id_(thread_id) {}
            const char* what() const throw()
            {
                static std::string msg;
                stringstream ss;
                ss << "generic error in thread #" << thread_id_;
                msg = ss.str();
                return msg.c_str();
            }
            int thread_id_;
        };

        template<class EX>
        class traced_error : virtual public std::exception, virtual public EX
        {
        public:
            traced_error(int line, const EX& ex):   EX(ex), line_(line) { }
            const char* what() const throw()
            {
                static std::string msg;
                stringstream ss;
                ss << "traced error on line " << line_ << " : '" << EX::what() << "'";
                msg = ss.str();
                return msg.c_str();
            }
            int line_;
        };

        template<class EX> traced_error<EX> make_traced_error(int line, const EX& ex)
        {
            return traced_error<EX>(line, ex);
        }
}

    int main()
    {
        try
        {
            throw ex::make_traced_error(__LINE__, ex::generic_error(234));
        }
        catch( const ex::generic_error& gex )
        {
            cout << "gex = " << gex.what();
            return 2;
        }
        catch( const exception& ex )
        {
            cout << ex.what();
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

When compiling the line `throw ex::make_traced_error(__LINE__, ex::generic_error(234));`  the compiler emits:

```
1>hacks_vs10.cpp(51): warning C4673: throwing 'ex::traced_error<EX>' the following types will not be considered at the catch site
1>          with
1>          [
1>              EX=ex::generic_error
1>          ]
```

One of the goals of this exception library is to append source file information to every thrown exception.  I use a macro that evaluates to `throw ex::make_traced_error(__FILE_, __LINE__, ex);`, but that was not necessary to replicate the compiler warning.

`make_traced_error` instantiates a template exception class, the template parameter for which is the exception being thrown, in this case `generic_error`.  Obviously if I simply throw a plain `generic_error` the compiler is happy, but this is not what I want to do.

What is the cause and effect of this warning?  Is the compiler wrong, or is my code?  I should note a couple things here.

First, when I execute this code it does what I expect it to do.  The `generic_error` catch block is called rather than the general `exception` block, and the output of the program is:

> gex = traced error on line 51 :

Second, when I compile this code with the [Comeau online compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout) it compiles without error or warning, suggesting to me that my code is Standards-compliant and legal C++.  Correct assumption?

> 'generic error in thread #234'

Finally, I have seen the [MS knowledge base article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32y577d8.aspx) about this warning.  But MS's explanation was fully unsatisfactory (it did not explain the cause of the warning), and their resolution is unacceptable -- they say that I should just throw a straight `generic_error`.

Comment: I would guess that this is a spurious warning.  Note that it says "the following types," but there are no types listed.

Comment: @James:  I believe the "following types" refers to the next line in which it mentions `generic_error`.  MS compiler errors are often multi-line

Comment: The `with [ ... ]` part is specifying that when it says `'ex::traced_error<EX>'` in the first line of the error, the template arguments of the instantiated template are what are listed in the `...` part.  If you change `traced_error` to use private inheritance, you'll get another line that lists `ex::generic_error` as a type that will not be considered at a catch site.

Comment: Any reason to not use [`boost::exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) here? (Not trying to rip; just curious)

Comment: @Billy: Can't use boost for a couple reasons.  One, I want this library to be as dependency-free as possible so that I can plop it on any box and start coding.  Two, more restrictive, current company policy prohibits using Boost in production code.  Why is a story for another show...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is indirectly about the multiple virtual inheritance from `std::exception`. The compiler gets confused because of it, but forgets to tell you why. :-/

[James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) is right: the compiler promises to mention a type, but it doesn't. Try without the `template`:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class Base: virtual public std::exception {};
class Derv: public Base, virtual public std::exception {};

int main()
{
  try {
    throw Derv();
  } catch (const Base &) {
    return 2;
  } catch (...) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

When compiled with level 4 warnings, this says nothing more than:

> warning C4673: throwing 'Derv' the following types will not be considered at the catch site

I see the value of warnings. But apparently level 4 is buggy in this case. As all works as expected you could just silence the compiler:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4673)
```

I guess you could report this case as a bug to Microsoft. The compiler should state the type and what the problem is.

Comment: My code compiles fine in Comeau and GCC, and from my reading of the Standard it is correct.  The program also behaves correctly.  All indications are that this is indeed a compiler bug, but given especially that is has existed since at least VC9, I want to be sure.  In addition, I'd rather not disable the warning, as this would disable not only false positives but true positive.

Comment: @John Dibling: Believe me "it's been there for so long" doesn't mean that it isn't a bug. Look at this gem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/05/12/override-atlthrow-with-care.aspx it's been there since VC++7 and is present in VC++10 for sure and noone knows when it'll be fixed.

Comment: @John: Disabling the warning shouldn't hide true positives, as it doesn't hide the warning about the actual cause. In the case described in MSDN: `warning C4670: 'Base' : this base class is inaccessible`