# Understanding C4673 compiler warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

The MSDN article on warning [C4673](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32y577d8.aspx) includes this example, which issues the warning with specific message:

```
Base: this base class is inaccessible
```

> ```
> // C4673.cpp
> // compile with: /EHsc /W4
> class Base {
> private:
>    char * m_chr;
> public:
>    Base() {
>       m_chr = 0;
>    }
>
>    ~Base() {
>       if(m_chr)
>          delete m_chr;
>    }
> };
>
> class Derv : private Base {
> public:
>    Derv() {}
>    ~Derv() {}
> };
>
> int main() {
>    try {
>       Derv D1;
>       // delete previous line, uncomment the next line to resolve
>       // Base D1;
>       throw D1;   // C4673
>    }
>
>    catch(...) {}
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, the MSDN article fails to give any explanation of the issue. I do not understand what's wrong with the above code. Why does it give a warning?

This is MSVC 2013 - v120 toolset.

Comment: It's difficult to offer any suggestions not seeing the code

Comment: @Petr: as I said, the code is in the MSDN article. I'll paste it here.

Comment: Then I suggest rewording your question to something like "I don't understand the example at..." and not mentioning your code at all.

Comment: @Petr: my question is well-stated as it is for anyone who would actually read it and not just skim through.

Comment: Also I suggest you post the full warning message, as MSDN says "Read the warning for each specific type for more information."

Comment: @Petr: The specific message is `the base class is inaccessible`.

Comment: FWIW, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585144) SO Q&A that seems to indicate this particular warning sometimes gets issued without good cause. Also FWIW, I've added feedback to MSDN that the article about the warning is not helpful, since it fails to point out what it is warning *about*. I *assume* it is something specific to MSVC's exception handling mechanism.

Comment: I could understand the warning if it was `catch (Base&)`, but not `catch (...)`

Comment: @DevSolar: there's multiple inheritance in the question you've linked, which is not so in my case.

Comment: @Barry: `catch` doesn't matter, the warning is generated at `throw` site and doesn't seem to be affected by `catch`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: That's why I didn't flag this as potential duplicate. Just collecting info on this warning -- with is surprisingly hard to come by.

Comment: @Barry, does not it try to say exactly that: seeing that OP throws a class with a private base class, it warns that if ever someone will try `catch (Base&)`, it would not work? I understand the warning is on `throw`, not on `catch` line.

Comment: @Petr Oh you're right, I misread the wording. That's... a pretty useless warning, given that we're not actually trying to catch by `Base&`

Comment: @Barry, but the `catch` could have been far away, even in a different compilation unit... Is not it too much to expect from a compiler to notice that the `catch` is here?

Comment: @Petr Yes, but typically you'd warn about things you're probably doing wrong now - not about things you potentially may be doing wrong somewhere else, possibly in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this on [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) and the full text of the warning is:

> main.cpp(28): warning C4673: throwing '`Derv`' the following types will not be considered at the catch site
>   main.cpp(28): warning C4670: '`Base`': this base class is inaccessible

That is true. If we had:

```
try {
    throw Derv();
}
catch (Base& ) {
    std::cout << "I caught it!";
}
```

That handler wouldn't match the `Derv` exception, since `Derv` inherits privately from `Base` and so that base class is inaccessible. So in this example, the exception would be uncaught.

However, it's a weird warning to emit as in the MSDN example, the exception will be caught with:

```
catch(...) {}
```

So it seems that the warning doesn't actually check for anything - it's just a general-issuance warning that you may be doing something harmful, without actually checking if you are or not. That doesn't seem like a particularly useful warning to me. If we were catching by `Base&`, yes - tell me that that's not going to happen - but we're catching by `...`.

Comment: So that's what it is! Private inheritance! I didn't notice. Changing it to public solves the issue.

Comment: ...and adding that `catch( Base & )` in the example, or even *omitting* the `catch( ... )`, would have made it crystal-clear what the warning is about. Another one of those MS gems...

Comment: Warning about `catch (Base&)` wouldn't be correct. Suppose there's a translation unit that includes the definition of Base, but not Derv. The compiler wouldn't know that Derv inherits privately from Base, so it won't have a way to issue the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more reduced example:

```
class Base { public: virtual ~Base() {} };

class Derived : private Base {};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    throw d;  // C4673
}
```

The problem here is that a developer might write a `throw` statement like that as part of any function and then expect the resulting exception to be caught polymorphically as a `Base`. This won't work, because the inheritance is `private`. You have to either catch `Derived` or `...`.

The reason why a warning is appropriate here is that you don't just `throw` any object. Usually, you have specific exception types which are used just for that. It does not make any sense to use private inheritance for such exception types. It will just introduce confusing behavior like this but there are no real use cases.

Unfortunately, the only place where we can detect whether a class is an exception type is in the `throw`, so that's the only place where we can generate this warning.